# Does iOS apps have a file like Android's APK?

Tags: ios

Android apps have a **single** APK file where I can easily import from my computer to my device and install it. I believe that iOS has ipa files but do they behave exactly like Android's APK files where I can send it to people and have them install the ipa file onto their idevice?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to distribute your app to a mass audience other than the app store. (There are some ways to distribute apps to a small audience, such as an ad-hoc release or TestFlight, but this probably isn't what you want)

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can send the .ipa to people and they can install it just like a apk provided:

a) the recipient's iPhone device id has been added to the provisioning profile, there is a limit of 100 devices or

b) its an enterprise app as opposed to one intended to go on the app store

Comment: Would I need a hold of their physical idevice in order to add them to the provisioning profile?

Comment: No, if they connect their phone to iTunes, then go to the summary page for the device, they will see the Serial Number for the device. If they click on Serial Number it will change to UDID. Get them to send you the UDID and then add that to the list of devices in your Apple account online, then add those devices to the relevant provisioning profiles, re-download those profiles using Xcode and rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Yes their is another file format of iOS app

It is app_name.app file which create to build your app.

i m also prefer .app file its very easy and fast.

Product -> Clicked on Build

Now see in your app product folder have .app file

Comment: Where does the  .app file located? I can't find